# Updating Server Side Session in a Next JS app with Next Auth

Tags: reactjs, typescript, session, next.js13, next-auth

I am working on setting up a manager role and trying to make it so when the manager clicks on an emplyee. They can then click on one of their jobs and see the details of the job. The issue I am running into is, I have a value "viewAsRepId" which is initially null. When they click on an employee, I have this handle click function that should update that value to the ID of the employee the manager is trying to see customers for.

```
  async function handleClickEmployee(id: number) {
    console.log("Send Update to DB for viewAsRepId: ", id);
    await update({ ...session, user: { ...session?.user, viewAsRepId: id } });
    void router.push(`/reps/${id}`);
  }
```

In the Session Callback, I am able to see the update method updated the value for "viewAsRepId". When I return the newSession the value is updated, but only on the client side.

Here is the Session Callback:

```
    async session({ session, trigger, newSession, user }) {
      if (trigger === "update" && newSession.user.viewAsRepId) {

        console.log("Session before update: ", session);
        session = newSession;
        console.log("New Session: ", session);

        return newSession;
      }

      const userWRole = user as SessionUser;

      return {
        ...session,
        user: {
          ...session.user,
          id: userWRole.id,
          role: userWRole.role,
          kingsId: userWRole.kingsId,
          qbUserName: userWRole.qbUserName,
          employeeId: userWRole.employeeId,
          dealership: userWRole.dealership,
          reps: userWRole.reps,
          customersKingsIds: userWRole.customersKingsIds,
          viewAsRepId: 0,
        },
      };
    },
```

You can see below the if condition the values the initial session is given.

The problem is I am using the getServerSideProps function to verify the manager should be able to see that reps customers and details. So when I call getServerAuthSession I would assume I should see the updated value, but that is not the case.

Reading the documentation I thought that it is saying it should update the session on both client and server side.

https://next-auth.js.org/getting-started/client#updating-the-session
'Assuming a strategy: "database" is used, the update() method will trigger the session callback with the trigger: "update" option. You can use this to update the session object on the server.'

I have tried to update the session using the update method from import { useSession } from "next-auth/react"

I expected this to update the session on both client and server side.

Ive also tried just updating the DB and calling that managers user to verify the url hasnt been edited. This works but adds a lot of load time and initially it just goes back to the dashboard because I told it to route there if the user was not under the list of employees for that manager. Then it goes to the right employees jobs page. So it does a weird double load.